# Flash Card Mode!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have another feature request for Stack Overflow... **Flash Card mode**! Imagine a system where you could upload all of your homework question from your CS 101 course, get them answered by professionals for free, and then after reading all the answers review them in a mode that concealed the answer until you hit a button signaling that you were ready for the spoiler.

Here is how it goes:

1. Ask a question that you don't get on SO.. Here is a good example -- though mine isn't from a CS 101 course -- [Haskell dividing num](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816993/haskell-dividing-num).
2. Enter FLASH-CARD MODE on the Haskell tag.
3. See if you've learned enough to get the right answer, or remember the points of the best answer.

I think this will greatly improve the educational quality of Stack Overflow.. There are [4106 questions tagged homework (as of Jul 29, 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) realistically we should do a better job helping those trying to learn, rather than just pragmatically solving their problems. This might also open the door for SO to one day compete with the University of Pheonix or some other online college. There is a lot of money to be made in the online educational sector, probably more than just a mere professional Q/A network.

Answer (score 14):

This already exists, sort of, courtesy of our very own [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha)!

http://notarealquestion.appspot.com/

Comment: That is **awesome!!!!**

Answer (score 6):

If you want  a flash card app, you could always create it yourself using the [API](https://stackapps.com/) or [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).

Comment: Perfect example. Hell that could even win a prize if you can get it submitted in the next 48 hours and get it +5 votes

Comment: @farseeker please tell more. what do you mean a prize? like 1k exp?

Comment: @Farseeker: No... I think based on the apps that are already there you'd need far more than just 5 upvotes.

Comment: @Evan: See my answer below. (Forget about getting a prize.)

Comment: @George, but 5 is all you need to get onto the `apps` page, and that's what you need to be in the running.

Comment: @Farseeker: I thought it was 6.

Comment: @Evan, fo shizz, you can [win prizes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-contest/) by building an app that's popular and uses the Stack Exchange API. Better start now, the clock is ticking... (I would genuinely give it a +1 just because it's *unique*)

Comment: @George, I dunno, maybe it is 6. Or maybe it's just showing the top *n*...

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to answer this seriously, Evan, because I'm taking it in good faith that this is a serious question.

Since it's very unlikely that (read *never*) the SO team will implement this on the site itself, why don't you write an application with Python or whatever that does something like this. It would be quite simple to do. Even if you have no skill writing applications, post a request on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com) and maybe someone will write it for you if you can demonstrate a need for it.

Answer (score 2):

Like Simon said, you could create your own app.

Here is a super primitive version of what you want:

http://peter-ajtai.com/examples/php/so.php

It takes the 10 most recent questions and it displays only the ones with answers. There are "Show me the answer!" buttons for each answer that reveal the answer..... looks a little ugly due to lack of any CSS, etc, but it gets the job done.

I'll probably keep working on it to add styling, the ability to browse questions, tags, etc. But I'm not sure when. Feel free to clone the code and run with it.

If you scroll to the bottom of the page, you can see all the code I used to create it (2 PHP files).

---

Edit:

Added in some tag browsing, you can click and pick right now, or type it in to the url, so to look at questions tagged `homework` in flashcard mode simply go to: [**http://peter-ajtai.com/examples/php/so.php?tag=homework**](http://peter-ajtai.com/examples/php/so.php?tag=homework)